# Trigger Before Insert in a table with JSON

Tags: mysql, json, triggers

I have a table with a **column containing JSON attributes**, and I want to do a **Trigger Before Insert**, but I have some doubts about how can I get the new values from JSON if these data still are not recorded on the table?

For example, below the **JSON** from the **Table_A**

```
JSON<br>
{<br>
  "**group**": "XYZ",<br>
  "**doc**": 12345  
}
```

Hereunder the trigger content doing a SELECT before run:

```
select id from TABLE_B
where group = (select JSON->>'$.group'  from TABLE_A)
and doc = (select JSON->>'$.doc'  from TABLE_A)
```

Please could you help me with this issue?

Comment: it is absolutely unclear what you want a trigger on which table and what should it do exactly. ALL VALUES are in the row `NEW` so you can get all columns by `NEW.id`

Comment: Provide: sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, the INSERT query with new row to be inserted, desired final data state.

Comment: Sorry you are correct! I meant about get the attribute from JSON and Query it in another table with NEW.